# Having issue with testing paypal sandbox.

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Using paypal sandbox to test MP Payments on new marketplace site.  It was working fine, now getting issue:

Getting php error message = fopen(https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Comment: You are probably running into the [POODLE problem](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vulnerability/).  I would recommend using cURL instead of fopen.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the beginning of January, PayPal made several security changes in Sandbox.
In order to reach out Sandbox endpoint, you must be compliant with the following requirements:

- TLS1.2
- HTTP1.1
- SHA-256

For further reference, please use the following link:
[TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 Upgrade](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1914&expand=true&locale=en_US)